# OCR functionality in Expo

Tags: expo, text-extraction

Does Expo support/provides any functionality/API for text extraction from both the IMAGE and AUDIO inputs (without needing to eject from Expo) ?

Answer (score 0):

Modules related to the image are [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/).

The module for audio is [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/audio/).

If you want to extract the values of these modules, you can extract them as console.log() or  at the module invocation section.
Please leave a comment for further questions.